# UINavigationController as a child of UITabBarController leaves a gap

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my app I have a UITabBarController as the root view. I have two step modal view that will be navigated through using a navigation controller. I'm running into an issue where when I add a UINavigationController as a child of the UITabBarController, a tab bar sized gap is left at the bottom of my navigation controller. See the attached image (apologies for the ugliness, it's just for demo purposes).

[image]

In the image, the bottom white bar is the tab bar, the blue background is the currently selected tab's view controller. The yellow is the view controller contained in the navigation controller. The red is the gap that is created when adding a navigation controller as a child to the tab bar controller.

This only occurs when the tab bar is set to opaque. Edges for extended layout on the navigation controller make no difference. It seems no matter what I do, I'm left with the gap that I can't do much of anything with.

I'm adding the navigation controller in a pretty straightforward way:

```
    addChildViewController(navigationController)
    view.addSubview(navigationController.view)
    navigationController.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[view]-20-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view" : navigationController.view]))
    view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-100-[view]-100-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["view" : navigationController.view]))
```

If I set the navigation controller as the root view controller in the app delegate, it displays correctly, without the gap at the bottom.

Is this a bug with the interaction between tab bars and navigation controllers or is there something I can do to prevent this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The view controller contained in the navigation needs the extended edges set. Additionally, `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` must be set to `true` on the contained view controller. I added the following to the view controllers that will be contained in the navigation controller:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.Bottom
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @Dave I never really got down to the "why," it was working so I just moved on. It seems like the child view controller is expecting the tab bar at the bottom and makes room for it, even though the positioning of the view controller means that there shouldn't be any consideration for it.

Comment: @SeanKladek - You are my hero. If I could vote this up 100 times I'd do it.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and the only thing that needed to be set for me was:

extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

This was on XCode 10.2.1 and the navigationVC was a child of the VC being displayed by the UITabBarController