# Gap between UIView containing table view and tab bar

Tags: swift, uitableview, space

I am experiencing a UI issue since iOS 15 where there is a gap between the tab bar and my UIView(UIViewController's view).

I tried to hide the toolbar as advised from several posts but this is still not working.

For more details, I created a mockup of the actual issue.

[image: view layout]

I have already set the tableView.sectionFooterHeight to zero which has therefore diminish the space but there is still a gap.

I am unsure what should be done next as no other solution has been found yet.

Your help or advise will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.

Thanks to this post: [UINavigationController as a child of UITabBarController leaves a gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682720/uinavigationcontroller-as-a-child-of-uitabbarcontroller-leaves-a-gap)

Basically, I added those settings in the ViewControllerOne:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.Bottom
extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```